# Rake db:create is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Running `rake db:create` is not working. Here is the stacktrace:

```
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
rake aborted!
LoadError: Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile.)

/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:377:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:50:in `resolve_hash_connection'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:29:in `spec'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:in `establish_connection'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:101:in `create_database'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:62:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:62:in `each'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:62:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'

Gem::LoadError: pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile.
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:377:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:50:in `resolve_hash_connection'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:29:in `spec'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:in `establish_connection'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:101:in `create_database'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:62:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:62:in `each'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:62:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'

Tasks: TOP => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Update all the bundle gems and then try to create the DB.

Comment: Please post your gemfile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says:

> pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile.

To do so simply go to your Rails app directory and open the `Gemfile` and place the following into it.

#### Example Config:

Gemfile:

```
# Use PostgreSQL as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
```

database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: 
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myawesomeapp_dev

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: myawesomeapp_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: myawesomeapp_prod
```

After you've added the line, save your file and hit `bundle install` in your rails app directory to install the required gem.

Also be sure to have a user on your PostgreSQL instance which is allowed to `connect` and to `create` new databases. You don't need to create the databases by yourself.

Comment: Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"myapp_test", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"myapp", "password"=>nil} now it is giving this error

Comment: Do you have a running PostgreSQL instance with the user/role `myapp` which is granted `connect` and `create`?

Comment: No then I should create a user/role for my app in postgresql

Comment: Yes, just create the user and grant the privileges. Rails will create the required databases for you.

Comment: /Users/mounikasmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
myapp already exists
myapp already exists -----it is showing this error!!

Comment: You should not create the database, only the user. Rails will create the database for you.

Comment: Sorry, but you should work your way step per step through the Rails tutorial first: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html